# Timing Issue using clock_gettime(), behaving oddly

Tags: c, linux, time

each time i run this program it seems to break in the "too slow" branch and does so at different times. For example, it will be running faster than 4 microseconds then suddenly take 25-45 milliseconds. Anyone have an idea why?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  struct timespec ts;
  long currTime, prevTime, timeStep;
  currTime = prevTime = timeStep = 0;

  while (1)
  {
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);

    prevTime = currTime;
    currTime = ts.tv_nsec;
    timeStep = currTime - prevTime;

    printf("delta: %lu, currTime: %lu\n", timeStep, currTime);

    if (timeStep > 16666667 && prevTime != 0)
    {
      printf("too slow\n");
      break;
    }

    if (timeStep < 0 || currTime > 990000000)
    {
      printf("overflow (or close to it)");
      break;
    }

  }//end while

}//end main
```

Comment: main should be at least `int main(void){}`

Comment: well in K&R they have it how i have written it... changing to your form doesn't seem to have an effect on the behaviour of my program

Comment: You will notice it in another Enviroment, but this is not the case to discuss here.

Comment: A good compiler should warn you about that `warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]`

Comment: Noticeable by its absence is any reference to `ts.tv_sec` so when the `ts.tv_nsec` wraps you will get a discontinuity.

Comment: thanks I think that would trigger the "overflow" branch... someone told me this is a normal issue in a multi-tasking operating system and suggested I try giving my program higher priority

Comment: You are trying to second-guess what consititutes an overflow with magic numbers.

Comment: i'm fairly confident that the overflow is not the issue at hand here, what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: I suggest moving printf to only 'too slow' or 'overflow' cases, that should keep timeStep to be in limits (or) save values into an array and print at the end

Comment: yeah moving the printf to the branch cases seems to fix it but i don't know why... i realize printf has to "do work" but i figured it would serve as a minimalist stand-in for my later "do work code"... on the other hand why would it fail at different times and not always at the same time...

Comment: it seems something specific is causing printf to take particularly long at certain points...

Comment: try replacing printf with write. printf buffering could be causing the issue

Comment: `%lu` expects an `unsigned long`, you pass a `long` -> UB

Comment: `printf()` writes to `stdout`, and `stdout` is buffered by default.  Likely at least some of the points where it consumes extra time occur when it flushes its buffer to the output device.

Comment: it looks like writing to terminal is the culprit, when output is re-directed to a file, I do not see it going to 'too slow' branch at all